# python truncating a dictionary to get last elements

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary of the form:

```
{"1":"sdv","2":"wefc","3":"sdsdv","4":"dvsdv","5":"igsdhc","6":"gvvxAS","7":"sdvsfdv","8":"sdagf"}
```

I need to remove the first 6 elements in this dictionary and take the remaining once only. The length of the list may vary but will always be greater than 6.

Please help me

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. What would you define as the 'first 6' here?

Comment: You could always look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict if I understood your intent correctly.

Comment: Dictionaries have no order and if your dictionary keys are just integers then use a list. Lists have a pop function to take off the last item and return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary doesn't actually have an ordering in its keys. You can take the keys, sort them, and manually remove the first 6 of them:

```
d = {
   "1":"sdv","2":"wefc","3":"sdsdv","4":"dvsdv",
   "5":"igsdhc","6":"gvvxAS","7":"sdvsfdv","8":"sdagf"
}

for key in sorted(d, key=int)[:6]:
    del d[key]

print d
```

Result:

```
 {'7': 'sdvsfdv', '8': 'sdagf'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way for doing it is:

```
dct = {"1":"sdv","2":"wefc","3":"sdsdv","4":"dvsdv",
       "5":"igsdhc","6":"gvvxAS","7":"sdvsfdv","8":"sdagf"}
dct = {k:v for k, v in dct.items() if int(k)>6}
print(dct)
```

Result:

```
{'8': 'sdagf', '7': 'sdvsfdv'}
```